# Toast build for orsay not working

Tags: cordova, samsung-smart-tv, television

I create an application for smart tvs with TOAST project. During the development I test everything with tizen emulator and tizen studio and everything was fine.

After finishing development I tried to run the application on both orsay TV and orsay emulator and unfortunatly there was a lots of issue in that platform. I fixed some issues in design but I can't fix the main issue.

When I run the application, There is a line in console that say : `deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds`. And I can't use any of the TOAST api functionalities.

I create an empty project and do exactly what this page say: https://github.com/Samsung/cordova-plugin-toast#prepare-to-start

But again I got the same error. Please help me.

Here is the log:

`cordova/platform: orsay bootstrap BEGIN                                    cordova.js:1365
adding proxy for NetworkStatus                                              cordova.js:887
adding proxy for Console                                                    cordova.js:887
adding proxy for Device                                                     cordova.js:887
adding proxy for Globalization                                              cordova.js:887
cordova/platform: orsay bootstrap END                                       cordova.js:1460
adding proxy for toast.inputdevice                                          cordova.js:1880
    return Window                                                           cordova.js:1880
adding proxy for toast.tvwindow                                             cordova.js:1880
    return Window                                                           cordova.js:1880
adding proxy for toast.tvchannel                                            cordova.js:1880
adding proxy for toast.tvaudiocontrol                                       cordova.js:1880
adding proxy for toast.drminfo                                              cordova.js:1880
adding proxy for toast.application                                          cordova.js:1880
adding proxy for toast.Media                                                cordova.js:1880
Failed to load resource: fail to read a resource form decryptied file       file:///home/smarttv/Apps/xThreeApp/cordova_plugins.js
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.                                  cordova.js:1880
Channel not fired: onNativeReady                                            cordova.js:1880
Channel not fired: onCordovaReady                                           cordova.js:1880
Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady                                 cordova.js:1880
Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady                                       cordova.js:1880`

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Ok I just find out two things:

- when I run the application on the emulator with `Debug As/Samsung Smart Tv Emulator` the `devicereaday` won't fired but if I close the app in the emulator and and open it again from the app page in emulator, the `deviceready` event will work perfect
- Even with the above trick, when I navigate to the second page, `deviceready` again won't fire! (Even I tried to navigate to the current page but second attamp will fail to fire the `deviceready` event)

I tried lots of method to navigating to the second page but all have the same result. (I use methods like `window.location.href = url;` and `window.location.replace(url);` and ...)

Comment: did you tried this - https://github.com/Samsung/cordova-plugin-toast/issues/17 ?

Comment: @Gandhi It has the same problem that I mention in my post update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I answer to myself, It was a bug in cordova.js

To fix this issue, you can change the bootstrap function to the following source code in cordova.js:

```
bootstrap: function() {
    console.log('cordova/platform: orsay bootstrap BEGIN');

    var modulemapper = require('cordova/modulemapper');
    var channel = require('cordova/channel');
    var SEF = require('cordova/plugin/SEF');
    var isWebapisLoaded = false;
    var isOnShowEventFire = false;

    modulemapper.clobbers('cordova/exec/proxy', 'cordova.commandProxy');

    var fireNativeReadyEvent = function() {
        if(isWebapisLoaded && isOnShowEventFire) {
            channel.onNativeReady.fire();
        }
    };

    for (var k in define.moduleMap) {
        if (/cordova.*\/proxy/.exec(k)) {
            require(k);
        }
        if (/cordova.*\/symbols/.exec(k)) {
            require(k);
        }
    }

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/webapi/1.0/webapis.js';
    script.onload = function() {
        isWebapisLoaded = true;
        fireNativeReadyEvent();
        require('cordova/plugin/ime-via-input');
    };
    head.appendChild(script);

    window.onPause = function () {
        channel.onPause.fire();
    };

    window.onResume = function () {
        channel.onResume.fire();
    };

    window.onHide = function() {
        localStorage.clear();
    };

    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var AppCommonPlugin = null;
        var NNaviPlugin = null;

        window.onShow = function () {
            localStorage.setItem('showEventFlag', 'true');
            settingInfo();
        };

        if(localStorage.getItem('showEventFlag') == 'true') {
            settingInfo();
        }

        if(window.curWidget && typeof window.curWidget.setPreference == 'function') {
            console.log('window.curWidget');
            window.curWidget.setPreference('ready', 'true');
        }
    });

    window.addEventListener('unload', function () {
        SEF.close();
    });

    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        switch(e.keyCode) {
            case 88: // RETURN key
                // default action disabled.
                // Calling 'setPreference('return', 'true')' is needed explicitly to exit the application
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            case 45: // EXIT key
                // NOTHING to prevent.
                break;
        }
    });

    function settingInfo() {
        try {
            AppCommonPlugin = SEF.get('AppCommon');
        }
        catch(e) {
            Error(e);
        }
        AppCommonPlugin.Execute('UnregisterAllKey');
        AppCommonPlugin.Execute('RegisterKey',29460); //up
        AppCommonPlugin.Execute('RegisterKey',29461); //down
        AppCommonPlugin.Execute('RegisterKey',4); //left
        AppCommonPlugin.Execute('RegisterKey',5); //right
        AppCommonPlugin.Execute('RegisterKey',29443); //enter
        AppCommonPlugin.Execute('RegisterKey',88); // return

        try {
            NNaviPlugin = SEF.get('NNavi');
        }
        catch(e) {
            Error(e);
        }

        NNaviPlugin.Execute('SetBannerState',2);
        isOnShowEventFire = true;
        fireNativeReadyEvent();
    }

    // End of bootstrap
    console.log('cordova/platform: orsay bootstrap END');
}
```